# Get redirect Uri from apache HttpResponse java

Tags: java, redirect, httpresponse

The librarian method returns the apache HttpResponse object. I need to get the redirection Uri. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get redirect Uri you have to do 2 things:

1. Set redirecting to your HttpClient instance:

   HttpClient httpclient = getNewHttpClient();
   HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(httpclient.getParams(), false); // necessary to detect redirection
2. Get redirection Uri from HttpResponse instance after request:

   response.getLastHeader("Location").getValue();

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use  `Location` header:

```
response.getLastHeader("Location").getValue();
```